# tinymce doesnt work for textarea in the <iframe> tag

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4, sizzle

tinymce doesnt work for textarea in the  tag

does it have any solution ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea"   
});                 
</script>
</head><body><iframe src="inner.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>


inner.htm:
<form method="post" action="somepage">
  <textarea name="content" style="width:100%" id="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iframe is like separate page and you do not have access to iframe content from perspective of main page. if it would be possible it would be security risk.

if you really want to do this you should move tinymce initiation (loading of scripts and css) to inner.htm

important note is that using iframe is rather bad idea, better use some framework/templating to handle reusable parts of website